# How to scan a line of 2 numbers separated by a space and assign each digit of each number to an int?

Tags: java, parsing, int, java.util.scanner

Basically, I have a file that will have a few lines of numbers similar to this:

4450 137

123679 5886

5448103 548913

I am writing a program to take each number, separate each of its integers, put them into a doubly linked list, then add them up.

The problem that I am having is that I am not sure how to take the FIRST line, separate the digits in the first number, then separate the digits in the second number, do what I need with them, then come back and do the same for the second line, and so on. The output would look like:

4450 + 137 = 4587

123679 + 5886 = 129565

...and so on.

So far, I have...

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
int num1;
int num2;

    while (scan.hasNext()) // While there are still things to scan
    {               
        num = scan.nextInt();

        while(num%10 !== 0)
        {
            tempNum = num % 10;
            linkList.add(tempNum);
            num = num/10;
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think I misinterpreted your original question. Do you basically need to add all the numbers up on a given line?

Comment: From what I think you are trying to do, you need to use regex. Another way to do this would be to use `Scanner.nextInt();`

Comment: @Harvtronix, I saw your answer (I think it was yours) before you deleted it, and what you had said was what I was needing.

Comment: Oh okay cool I will re add it then haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thought process for me is like this:

- grab an int from scanner
- enter a loop that extracts each digit
- put each of those digits into your list
- continue doing this until you run out of digits
- grab next int from scanner

**How do you extract each digit?**

If your number is 12305 then you can strip off the 5 by doing `12305 % 10`, which will give you back 5. Then you discard that 5 by doing 12305 / 10 ( = 1230) and storing that result for the next time you loop around.

**How do you know when you've run out of digits?**

If your stored number / 10 gives you zero, then you're done with that int.

**Inner Loop Example:**

```
while(num != 0) {
  singleDigit = num % 10;
  ...
  num = num / 10;
}
```